# VNC (tigervnc) uses a lot of bandwidth

Tags: linux, vnc

I am using tigerVNC and even with -geometry 1024x768 and the lowest quality it consumes 2 megabytes/s of bandwidth, which is not the case for me (My internet connection is 200-500kb/s).

Is there a way to decrease bandwidth usage for VNC on ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe try another VNC client? I use RealVNC and it uses very little bandwidth when not doing things that need full screen refreshes. Though, as soon as I start dragging windows around or browsing websites with video or animated images, it uses about 1MB/s(8-10mb/s). Hopefully someone knows a way to improve the bandwidth efficiency for VNC in general..

Comment: I think it depends on server, not client

Comment: If I can make a "silly" suggestion.. DON'T USE VNC.  There is no need to push 100% of your display elsewhere (as VNC does).  XWindows aka X11 was actually designed (back in the day) to show everything remotely.   X11 allows for X11 forwarding which is better written and more integrated than VNC.  Windows has RDC which is better written and more integrated than VNC.  Mac has .. well.. mac just uses VNC..  VNC isn't bad.. just not as good as the native solutions you already have.

Comment: The problem is that I have to use it)